# Why is my inorder traveral failing to add to ArrayList but succeeding in printing correct values?

Tags: java

Given a binary tree, return the inorder traversal of its nodes' values.

For example:
Given binary tree [1,null,2,3],
   1
    \
     2
    /
   3
return [1,3,2].

Here's my code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public List<Integer> inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        helper(root, list);
        return list;

    }

    public void helper(TreeNode root, List<Integer> list){
        if (root == null){
            return;
        }
        if(root.left == null){
            System.out.println(root.val);
            list.add(root.val);
            inorderTraversal(root.right);
        }else{
            inorderTraversal(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.val);
            list.add(root.val);
            if (root.right != null){
                inorderTraversal(root.right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Print function gives 1,3,2 which is correct, but the list just returns [1]

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare new ArrayList in every inorderTraversal function. Try to make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in `helper` you are calling `inorderTraversal` which instantiates

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This seems a strange way to do recusrive, but anyway pass the `list` that you have in `helper` to `inorderTraversal`

Answer (score 0):

You are losing your `list` when calling `inorderTraversal` from `helper`. Either replace

```
inorderTraversal(node);
```

with

```
helper(node, list);
```

or

```
list.addAll(inorderTraversal(node));
```

Also your method contains redundant complexity, you can just write:

```
public void helper(TreeNode root, List<Integer> list) {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    helper(root.left, list);
    System.out.println(root.val);
    list.add(root.val);
    helper(root.right, list);        
}
```